# Django Unicode error in Filed name

Tags: python, django, unicode, codec

I'd like to assign a human-readble name in Japanese that appears in Admin site.

so, simply I'd like to write like this way:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(u'投稿日時')
```

But then it says:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 57:
    ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I use unicode like Japanese in this case ?

full traceback:

```
python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 314, in validate
    raise CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 57: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: @MikeDeSimone it isn't: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714517/python-django-encoding-error-non-ascii-character-xe5/20714620#20714620) can help you.

Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of file, it define de encoding to utf-8 which is what you need

Comment: I did but it didn't help

Comment: I am sorry. I think it was my spelling miss or something.
I also did wrote `coding: utf-8` but after copying your one, it does work.

Comment: the cause was not about `coding` type. it was that I added field display name even to foreign key's column.