# Python Django: displaying special characters in admin, but not on my site?

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, utf-8

**Using the admin:**

I can put characters like this: `«æšʩЖあ☃»` into a textfield.
And those characters will then display correctly on the admin sidebar as "recent actions".

This tells me that there is someway that django is querying my database where these characters are being stored correctly and then represented correctly.

**Using Views.py**
If I do something like this in views.py:

```
var = '«æšʩЖあ☃»'
render_to_response( ... bla bla bla
{'var':var} .. bla bla...)
```

It shows up correctly on my webpage.

**However**
In my django app I have some manual connections going on to the database, written like so:
**myscript.py**

```
con = mdb.connect('mysql.server','name','password','mydb')
cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute(
            """SELECT * FROM swimsets_swimset"""
            )
container = cur.fetchone
myquery = container['column-name']

mylist.append(myquery)
```

**views.py**

```
 var = myscript.myfunction() # returns the mylist shown above
   render_to_response(...{'var':var}...)
```

It will however show the the list on the page as [ \x8890\x923\ etc, \1313\23x\ etc ]
and then if I print each item of the list, show absolutely nothing.

**What I've tried:**

Adding:    `con = mdb.connect('mysql.server','name','password','mydb',use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')`

adding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (to views and myscript.py)
adding: DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'UTF-8' (to settings.py)

I've read countless stacks and lots of documentation but I still just cant get it. Thanks appreciated.
[Python Django Encoding Error, Non-ASCII character '\xe5'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714517/python-django-encoding-error-non-ascii-character-xe5)

If I do this:
    var.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')

It seems to display SOME of the odd characters, but it isn't really a fix. I doubt this is how django is able to correctly display all sorts of unicode in the admin side panel.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I hate to be that guy who answers his own question, but this one issue has literally grounded me for days, I even had another stack question up that I deleted after it had zero responses. I got clearer on the problem hoping to get better help, but instead I got clear enough to debug it myself!

The totality of what worked to get Django to display the the special characters on the webpage instead of \x1231\d2314 was:

Adding:  `use_unicode=True, charset='utf8` to `con = mdb.connect('mysql.server','name','password','mydb',use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')`

adding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (to views and myscript.py) adding: `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'UTF-8'` (to settings.py)

and then finally, adding `unicode(var)` to myscript.py that was manually connecting to the database and loading query data into var.